# How can I use module Control.Monad.Free in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, installation

I try code in Haskell. I want to use module Control.Monad.Free. I written `import Control.Monad.Free` in my test.hs. But I have error:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Control.Monad.Free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.7.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) is defined in the [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package. You can install it with [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/):

```
cabal install free
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But before I installed control-monad-free. And now I have error: Ambiguous module name `Control.Monad.Free' How can I uninstall control-monad-free?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe something like `ghc-pkg unregister control-monad-free` could work

Comment: Thank you. I simply used "ghci -hide-package control-monad-free" when opened ghci.

Comment: @user3186861 the way you used isn't uninstalling; it just hides the package from ghci temporarily.